# Evaluate the given integral

Tags: integration

What is the simplest way to evaluate the integral $$\int x(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\, dx ?$$

Does trigonometric substitution $x=a \sin \theta$ work ?

Comment: Why not use just simple substitution $u=a^2-x^2$ and then you have $du=-2x \ dx$ so you just got to solve $ -\frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{u} \ du$

Comment: Substitute $a^2-x^2=z^2$

Comment: Trigonemetric substitution would be appropriate if you didn't have the $x$ out front, making the easier substitution possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easier route is to substitute $$u = a^2-x^2\implies du = -2x\,dx$$

Then you have $$\begin{align} \int x(a^2 - x^2)^{1/2}\,dx & = -\frac 12\int (\underbrace {a^2 - x^2}_u)^{1/2}\underbrace{(-2x\,dx)}_{du}\\ \\ & = -\frac 12 \int u^{1/2} \, du\\ \\ &= -\frac 12 \frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2} + C \\ \\ & = -\frac 13(a^2 - x^2)^{3/2} + C \end{align}$$

If you didn't have the $x$ factor in your integral, i.e. if you had only $$\int  \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}\,dx$$

...**then**, *yes*, trigonometric substitution would work nicely.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

First I do this the quick method, and than I fully explain your method of trig substation and shows they are equivalent!.

Let's do this nicely, would do this as follows
$$
I:=\int x(a^2-x^2)^{1/2}\, dx.
$$
Change of variables 
$$
y=(a^2-x^2)^{1/2},\quad y^2= a^2-x^2,\quad ydy=-xdx.
$$
Note by doing this substitution and squaring y before taking the derivative, we make the integrand something with no fractional exponents, to obtain
$$
I=-\int  y^2 \, dy=-\frac{y^3}{3} +C \to I=-\frac{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}+C
$$
where C is a constant of integration.

Now note your method using $ x=a\sin y$ 
$$
I=|a|^3\int  \sin y (1-\sin^2 y)^{1/2} \cos y\, dy=|a|^3\int  \sin y \cos^2 y\, dy.
$$
Change of variables $u=\cos y$, we obtain
$$
I=-|a|^3 \int u^2 \, du = -\frac{|a|^3 u^3}{3}+C=-\frac{|a|^3}{3}\cos^3 y+C=-\frac{|a|^3}{3} \cos^3(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))+C=-\frac{|a|^3}{3}(1-x^2)^{3/2}+C.
$$
Your method works, but as you can see is a bit nastier and requires more work.  Hope this helped.

Comment: Someone downvoted this apparently for no reason, since it seems to be a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @user111187 Well thanks.   I tried to answer the OP and provide more.  People always down vote my stuff.

Comment: In your trigo approach, there is a tiny mistake: since you factor out $\sqrt{a^2}$, it should become $|a|$. Precision: I didn't downvote, of course.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You are right